# Replication sqlserver database to azure

Tags: azure, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

Scenario: I have a server farm to deploy my web site. I want to try to add one server from Azure platform. Every host has a replication from one database server. I have tried to add the replication database but I got this message error:

> Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is unable to access replication
>   components because replication is not installed on this instance of
>   SQL Server. For information about installing replication, see the
>   topic Installing Replication in SQL Server Books Online. (New
>   Subscription Wizard)

After this message I suppose that something is missing in the sqlserver database Azure side.

I have googled something to solve my problem but without luck.

I have found one tool (Azure SQL Data Sync) and tried something to solve the problem but it didn't work.
From the Azure documentation, I have found that until V12 of the azure database replication wasn't available. 
But what about v12?

Questions:Am I missing something with the version of the database? Should I change the database plan in Azure subscription?
Should I use some external tool that allow me to maintain sync my database server with the replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replication is not yet available according to the MSDN even on V12. You can use https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-introduction/ and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync/. You can write your own sync logic with change tracking, Service broker and linked servers / safe CLR but better use the existing tools.

Comment: Sirisha is correct. The following page lists the features that are currently not supported in V12. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336281.aspx#NotSupported. Data Sync or Data Factory would be the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Azure Data Factory Service could be a solution for you?
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-introduction/